# Does member function like operator<< , operator* need ADL to work?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a code snippet (Hypothetically):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Pirate {
 void song_name() {
  std::cout << "Bink's Sake\n";
 }

 Pirate& operator*(Pirate const& other) {
  // do something
  return *this;
 }
};

int main() {
 Pirate p1{} p2{};
 p1.song_name(); // does this use qualified or unqualifed name lookup?
 
 p1 * p2;

 std::cout << 5;
 std::cout << 'a';
}
```

Does `p1 * p2` use qualified name lookup or unqualified name lookup or ADL?

`std::cout << 5` transforms into `std::cout.operator<<(5);`
`std::cout << 'a'` transforms into `std::operator<<(std::cout, 'a');`

Does member functions require ADL to work?
Does the above two statments use qualified or unqualifed name lookup or ADL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A name is a **qualified name** if the scope to which it belongs is explicitly denoted using a **scope-resolution operator** (`::`) or a **member access operator** (`.` or `->`).

##### Case 1

Thus, when you wrote:

```
p1.song_name(); //here p1.song_name is a qualified name
```

In the above statement, `p1.song_name` is a **qualified name** and so here **qualified lookup** takes place.

##### Case 2

Next, when your wrote:

```
p1 * p2;
```

The above statement is equivalent to:

```
p1.operator*(p2);
```

Since your class `Pirate` have an overloaded member function `operator*`, the above statement will use that member function. The above statement uses **qualified lookup** as well because we have used the **member access operator** `.`.

##### Case 3

Here we have the statement:

```
std::cout << 5;
```

The above statement is equivalent to:

```
std::cout.operator<<(5);
```

which uses **qualified lookup** since it has member access operator `.`

##### Case 4

Here we look at the statement:

```
operator<<(std::cout, 'a');
```

Here the `char` overload from [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `ofstream` is used. This uses **ADL** because in this case the first parameter has a class type. So the compiler will also look in the namespace in which `cout` is defined. Thus, for this call, the compiler also looks in the `std` namespace and finds the `char` overload.

Comment: Does `std::cout << 'a'` uses unqualifed lookup or ADL since it's not a member fn?

Comment: @Vegeta I have added explanation for `std::cout << 'a';` as case 4. Check it out. Note that i have explained it considering that it is equivalent to `operator<<(std::cout, 'a');`

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks @Anoop

Answer (score 2):

The operators lookup non-static member functions like

```
std::cout.operator<<(5);
```

but also non-member functions via unqualified lookup and ADL if they have a non-member variant. All of these together form the overload set.

For this to work correctly non-member variants should be found via ADL, i.e. placed inside the namespace of the class for which they are overloading the operator. E.g. for overloading `operator<<` for your own classes you cannot use a member version, because the first argument is probably supposed to be anything derived from `std::ostream`. Then ADL on the non-member variant is the only way to make it work everywhere.